# looking for next ID before save in yii

Tags: yii

I'm trying to get the next product ID, but it says that I need to specify criteria... CDbCriteria. I searched around, I don't see other people using criteria so I must be doing something wrong?? I am looking for the next product_id.

```
    public function getNextID()
{
    $model = new Product();

    $last_ID= $model->findByAttributes(array('product_id'=>'product_id DESC'));
    $next_ID=$last_ID+1;

    return $next_ID;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need that next ID? This approach will fail if two or more requests are handled at exactly the same time. Use an autoincrementing primary key or an external solution that generates guaranteed non-repeating IDs.

Comment: maybe the incrementation is not by 1; this is a useless question;

Comment: oh good point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do not quite understand what to know before you insert id, but try to do so

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = 'id';
$criteria->order  = 'id DESC';
$criteria->limit = 1;
$product = Product::model()->find($criteria);
// id of last row
$lastId = $product->id;
```